# Function name throws UnboundLocalError when called

Tags: python-3.x

Alright, I'm losing my mind over here. I have the following fragment of code:

```
def gain(graph, partition, a, b):
    return (
              len(get_connected_external(graph, partition, a))
            - len(get_connected_internal(graph, partition, a))
        ) + (
              len(get_connected_external(graph, partition, b))
            - len(get_connected_internal(graph, partition, b))
        ) - 2*(b in graph[a])

def kernighan_lin_single_pass(graph, partition):
    locked = { node: False for node in graph }
    while False in locked.values():
        table = {}
        for a in partition[0]:
            for b in partition[-1]:
                table[(a, b)] = gain(graph, partition, a, b)
```

When I attempt to run this, python throws an `UnboundLocalError`, stating `local variable 'gain' referenced before assignment`. Except that `gain` isn't a local variable, it's a function defined right above this one. In fact, the offending line runs just fine in the debug console (VS Code). Intellisense even shows `gain` as a function when I hover over it.

What gives?

**EDIT:** Here's the full function, in case it's relevant.

```
def kernighan_lin_single_pass(graph, partition):
    locked = { node: False for node in graph }
    while False in locked.values():
        table = {}
        for a in partition[0]:
            for b in partition[-1]:
                table[(a, b)] = gain(graph, partition, a, b)

        max_gain = max(table.values())
        for pair, gain in table.items():
            if gain < max_gain:
                del table[pair]

        selected_pair = sorted(table.keys())[0]
        print(selected_pair)
        exit(1)

    return partition
```

Comment: Are those functions both actually at top level in your code? And is there anything else in `kernighan_lin_single_pass` that you didn't show us?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica The full function is a bit longer, but I don't think the parts after this are relevant.

Comment: The parts after it were indeed relevant.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica How so? Also, ignore those `print` and `exit` statements. Those were just for debugging.

Comment: I just realized what you meant...

Comment: The problem was caused by the presence of the line `for pair, gain in table.items():`, which wasn't in what you originally posted. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `gain` to mean two different things within the same scope. At first, it's a function you're calling, then later, it's the value of the items of the dictionary that you're iterating over. If a function assigns to a variable anywhere, then it's considered a local variable throughout, so your global `gain` is ignored. To fix it, rename either the `gain` function or the `gain` in `for pair, gain in table.items()`.